# Enable CORS request on deployed reactjs + springboot application

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, deployment, cors, google-compute-engine

I've got fullstack app with reactjs on frontend and springboot on backend. On localhost in works perfectly, but when I deployed it on google compute engine virtual machine it stopped working and started throwing CORS errors.
Code:
React:

```
class RegisterPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
....
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
}
....
handleRegister(event) {
...
axios.post('http://localhost:8443/api/v1/auth/sign-up', credentials)
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    requestResult: "registration successful!"
                })
            }).catch(resp => {
            this.setState({
                requestResult: "something went wrong :("
            })
        })
...
}
```

Also I added mappings to Spring:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PoisApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PoisApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What can be the problem? I am out of ideas right now, so any assistance would be great.

Edit: tried adding this to spring security

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and(). ...
...
}

@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
```

and even this

```
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000",
"http://my_ip:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin",
                "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Nothing helps!

Comment: how do you sending parameters?

Comment: what do you mean by sending parameters?

Comment: Remove `axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'`. Access-Control-Allow-Origin isn’t a request header.

Comment: deleted, it did not help :(

Comment: your sending credential type?

Comment: `const credentials = {email: this.state.email, name: this.state.name, password: this.state.password, patronymic: this.state.patron, surname: this.state.surname}`

Comment: try to send these credential using form-data object 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was different from what I thought. CORS error in browser console can mean 'no response from server' and this was the problem - my React frontend was making requests to wrong address (React server, deployed on google compute engine, was making requests to localhost - and somehow localhosts means my computer, the one I am using, and, obviously, I did not launch spring server on my localhost).
If someone has this problem check domain from which you are expecting response.